# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: I want to add javascript link to html dom with php simple dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom

I use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and I want to add javascript link to html dom.
Here is my code.

```
$html=  file_get_contents("http://example.com")
```

I want to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://exapmle.com/example.js"></script>
```

link to between head tag.
Anyone who knows solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$head_pos = strpos($html, '</head>'); // find position of the </head>
$newHtml = substr($html, 0, $head_pos) . $stringToAdd . substr($html, $head_pos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use strpos() and substr() to find position and then add.